# Grab a count of different values in object

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, winforms

When I make a web call through an API, it displays a JSON file. I have no problem with selecting certain data that I want. For this project we do not want to do that. We want to get a result for anything that has a status = 1 and display that count.

```
        List<stats> ls = new List<stats>();
        ls = rClient.makeRequest(txtURL1.Text);

        listBox1.DataSource = ls;
        listBox1.DisplayMember = "fullResult";

        var url = ls[1].ID;
        string access = ls[1].FirstAccessed;
        string endAccess = ls[1].LastAccessed;
        string count = ls.Count.ToString();
        string status = ls[int.Parse(count)- 1].Status;
        string intCon = url.ToString();
        dataOutput.Text = intCon + " " + access + " " + endAccess + "  " + count + " " + status;
```

As you can see I have select different parts of the JSON file. I did attempt to try and grab some of the information, but my results weren't great. I need a little bit of guidance for this. Just started playing around with C#.

The ListBox displays everything that comes from the API, so I kind of want to read all that data and pull the separate status codes that way.

JSON Output

```
[
    {
    "ID": 502,
    "WorkflowID": "5b7ac3e66eb51a0dcc287f84",
    "WorkflowName": "I9 Approval",
    "EngineID": null,
    "FilePages": null,
    "PortalID": 0,
    "Permissions": 0,
    "ProcessActions": null,
    "SSDocument": {
        "SSDBID": 1002,
        "SSArchiveID": 1,
        "SSDocumentID": 164
    },
    "LastAccessed": "2018-11-28T17:34:38.843Z",
    "FirstAccessed": "2018-11-28T17:34:38.843Z",
    "Status": 3, **<--- Want to read this here.**
    "CurrentNode": "-7",
    "Wait": 0,
    "WaitStart": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
    "Queue": null,
    "Properties": [
```

Parsing the JSON Here:

```
    public List<stats> makeRequest(string endPoint)
    {

        string strResponseVlaue = string.Empty;
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(endPoint);
        request.Method = httpMethod.ToString();
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("SSAdministrator:Password!"));
        HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;



        {
            if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("Error Code: "+ response.StatusCode.ToString());
            }
            //Process the response stream

        using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                if(responseStream != null)
                {
                    using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                    {
                        strResponseVlaue = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            } //End of Response Stream
        }// End Of Using Reponse

        var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<stats>>(strResponseVlaue);
        return obj;
```

There are 47 other results from the API.

Comment: You're going to have to edit your question and provide more details. Why have you included `ds`, it look slike you don't use it? I don't see your JSON. How are you parsing your JSON? Where are you trying to read `status == 1`?

Comment: @Jonathan I have since edited it. I have removed the ds, I am basically building on top of a frame I previously built for something else and that was for something very different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `status` is a property of the `stats` object, and you are getting a `List<stats>` after deserializing your JSON, you can get the count as follows:

```
using System.Linq;

var statusOneCount = ls.Count(i=>i.status == 1);
```

Comment: Worked wonders, I have been trying to figure this out for the last hour. Thank you for your time sir!